# How to declare a root variable in scss file so that the variable is accessible over all the components of my react project?

Tags: reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

I am trying to create a root variable which I could be able to access in any component of my react project.
The app starts without any issue but there isn't any reflection on the output part.
By inspecting in dev tools I am getting to know that my variable isn't declared.

I have created a reactproject in which I am having a app.scss file in the src foldder.
The code in app.scss file is:

```scss
:root {
  --main-color: #0b0b0b
}
```

I am trying to use that value in my home.scss file inside my home component.
The code in home.scss file is:

```scss
.home {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
}
```

Devtools says `--main-color is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

You declare your variable like this

```
$root-color: blue;
```

and then you import your file in your main component or in your main scss file.

You will need to have `node-sass` installed and `sass-loader` if you're using webpack.